# Subtype Polymorphism is broken in Cython v30.0.0a11?

Tags: python, cython

Trying to pass an instance of a derived class to a function which accepts instances of the superclass gives an error in Cython `v3.0.0a11`:

`test.pyx`:

```py
class MyInt(int):
    pass

def takes_int(a: int):
    pass
```

`try.py`:

```py
from test import takes_int, MyInt

takes_int(MyInt(1))
```

`try.py OUTPUT`:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO PC\PycharmProjects\MyProject\cython_src\try.py", line 3, in <module>
    takes_int(MyInt(1))
TypeError: Argument 'a' has incorrect type (expected int, got MyInt)
```

Changing to `v0.29.32`, cleaning the generated `C` file and the object files, and re-running, gets rid of the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is (kind of) expected.

Cython has *never* allowed subtype polymorphism for builtin type arguments. See https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#types:

> This requires an exact match of the class, it does not allow subclasses. This allows Cython to optimize code by accessing internals of the builtin class, which is the main reason for declaring builtin types in the first place.

This is a restriction which applies only to builtin types - for Cython defined `cdef` classes it works fine. It's also slightly different to the usual rule for annotations, but it's there because it's the only way that Cython can do much with these annotation.

What's changed is that an `int` *annotation* is interpreted as "any object" in Cython 0.29.x and a Python `int` in Cython 3. (Note that `cdef int` declares a C int though.) The reason for not using an `int` annotation in earlier versions of Cython is that Python 2 has two Python integer types, and it isn't easy to accept both of those and usefully use the types.

I'm not quite sure exactly what the final version of Cython 3 will end up doing with `int` annotations though.

---

If you don't want Cython to use the annotation (for example you would like your int class to be accepted) then you can turn off `annotation_typing` locally with the `@cython.annotation_typing(False)` decorator.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So does turning annotation typing off make the `int` annotated argument behave like a normal python object? Does this incur a speed cost?

Comment: Yes turning off annotation typing just makes the `int` annotated argument a normal Python object. Cython doesn't currently do much with Python `int` objects anyway (largely because of the need to support both the Py2 variants) so it shouldn't cost much speed. It'll be no worse that it was in 0.29.x anyway